# addMarker and moveCamera invalid declarations

Tags: java, android

I am implementing a map that needs to show your current location when ran. So far I have had no issues but today when following a tutorial on how to set your Lat and Lng I am having trouble initializing map markers for my project. addMarker and moveCamera cannot be resolved. I am using API 29 and maybe that is the problem as I am trying to force Android Studio to use the v4 fragment activity. My XML files are okay, this is my code. I think parts of my old code are clashing with the new tutorial I am following. I am asking for your support.

```
import android.Manifest;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;`


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class About extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {



    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    LatLng userLatLong;
    GoogleMap map;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    SearchView searchView;

    LatLng test= new LatLng(57, 2);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(test).title("Marker Test"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(test));


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);


        searchView = findViewById(R.id.sv_location);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                String location = searchView.getQuery().toString();
                List<Address> addressList = null;

                if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(About.this);
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location));
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });



        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    private void fetchLastLocation() {
      //  Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // store user latLong
                userLatLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                map.clear(); //clear old location marker
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(aberdeen).title("Marker in Aberdeen"));
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(aberdeen));
            }
        };
    }



}
```

This is the fragment we are having trouble with:

```
    LatLng test= new LatLng(57, 2);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(test).title("Marker Test"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(test));
```

It is saying that MarkerOptions is asking for a return type, but if I change it then tells me that position has private access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a posting error or your actually code but it is not correct.

You have placed code where normally there are memberVariableDeclarations.  This would be what the compiler is complaining about.

If this is just an error in the post - then correct the post and I'll remove this...

```
public class About extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {



    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    LatLng userLatLong;
    GoogleMap map;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    SearchView searchView;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //*** This section is misplaced ***//

    LatLng test= new LatLng(57, 2);  // this part can stay if needed but
                                     // next 2 lines definitely need to go.
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(test).title("Marker Test"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(test));
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Comment: Yes. I placed the code in the memberVariableDeclarations. I fixed the issue. Thank you for your help!